# How do I get ride of this nonstop crash, freeze, not booting issues?

Tags: boot, grub2, freeze

Made 12.04 64-bit USB bootable. Then I have been trying to install almost like twenty times to get succeed but still its failing / crashing/ freezing, after showing Grub screen.

What can I do to fix this? I have tried `nomodeset` and `vga=770`

Steps tried:

1. power on, bios shows
2. I select the kernel and press e to go in details and press F10 to boot
3. nothing just happens

Steps tried:

1. power on, bios shows
2. hold shift key to have grub
3. press f2 to go to grub command line

But unable to boot in the installed OS

Comment: There are more answers here http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: Also, it could be a hardware problem, the image damaged, the memory corrupted, the disk dying... etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing just happens" and "unable to boot"? *What* happens? Do you get a blank, black screen (or perhaps a blank screen with a blinking text cursor)? See [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/343063/25165 - except this there was no other solution for to fix it.