# Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit - GeForce GT 620 card is not working, always going to minimum graphics mode

Tags: 13.04, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I have GeForce GT 620 card connected in a Dell PC (Alienware x51) brand new. Used LiveCD to install, while installing the graphics was correct.

But after that i installed openbox and some more packages since then when i boot the grub screen shows but after that no graphics showing.

Comment: Will try OEM installation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Graphics Driver with Ubuntu is not shifted when kernel is updated or applied update-grub/grub or initramfs. So to fix it what we have done is as below:

Step 1:

```
vim /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
update-grub
update-grub2
reboot
```

now that we are in desktop with minimum graphics, we can move to next step

Step 2:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && software-properties-gtk
> failed (because it installed nvidia-310 which is old not compatible)

export DISPLAY=:0.0 && nvidia-xconfig
> failed (because xorg.conf file was created)

export DISPLAY=:0.0 && apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
> failed (because its installing more older version nvidia-304)
```

Step 3:

```
service lightdm restart (basically it restarts the Ubuntu or X windows system on the fly to get the latest changes, but failed - cause there is no latest driver it goes to minimum graphics)
```

Step 4: the real fix

```
put it in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
> blacklist nouveau
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-325
```

Step 5:

Works now

Optional: check the cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf or use xrandr to set correct resolution